# How do you get the Logo Text to fit with the logo

Tags: html, css

I've tried to do some basic CSS, but I'm having issues putting the title beside the logo image.

Here is an image of my code:

[image: I've made part of the nav bar, but I need help finding the right code to make the text fit with the logo]

I've used `display:inline;` to raise the text, but then I can't change it afterwards. The height is locked and it won't seem to cooperate.

So help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please post your code inside a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Tian, you may try to add

```
display: inline;
```

to both #header-image and #logo.
it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick re-write of the nav bar. You can try to alter it to fit yours, and throw an image in there to see it. May have to justify/move where you want your text in relation, but at least this gets it right next to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing</Title>
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="teststyles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="">
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1>Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
}

.img {
    display: flex;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
}
```